# MBP Late 2011 freezes under yosemite

Tags: macos, ssd, mouse, performance

I have an MacBook Pro Late 2011 and it freezes (So the Beachball is turning arround), not completely randomly but when I use the disks, (writing or reading data) over 1/2 Mb/s so if I copy a big file from a DMG it freezes often but randomly during the copy process, or if I download something over internet it freeze randomly during the download.
I can't do anything except of moving the mouse, if i wait a few seconds all comes back and I can continue use my Mac. I first thought it was totally random but it happens more often when I copy data or download anything. I think it's Yosemite's fault but I can not certify that.

Useful pasts:

**EtreCheck: https://paste.ee/r/UvuNe**

**Full console log: https://paste.ee/r/kxZgs**

**I already reinstalled OSX Yosemite, and after that it continued with the same issue, but before i reinstalled a fresh version, it hung up always randomly, after I reinstalled OSX on my Home made Fusion Drive it only hung up when i started copying files or other things like that**

I have read similar topics on internet about Yosemite and Freezing bug that was always different causes and different freezes like total freeze (no mouse) or freeze for infinite time and does not continue after a few secs.

When it freeze ALL stops even iTunes stop playing music. and after the freeze stops, everywhere i clicked clicks in a accelerated mode.
So if during the freeze i click on two apps and open a few menus, it does nothing but after a few secs all opens.

Anyone got the same issue or an idea to solve/troubleshoot this ?

Sorry for my English.

Edit: (my answer to  Buscar웃SD)
I already looked at the system monitor, i forget to say it i'll add it.
When the freeze happens the CPU is at 30% and disks are not at 100% when ii download but when I copy anything they are at 100% So it's weird, the amount of RAM used changes nothing, and the console writes nothing suspect

Edit2: I add a few images from the console and activity monitor during a freeze:

During the Freeze

[image: During the freeze]

Another during the freeze

[image: Another during the freeze]

And this is after the freeze

[image: after the freeze]

I have another screenshot who is important and it's the lines during the FREEZE, theses lines are these after the blue selected line
On the screenshot we can see that the freeze during from 20:20:58 and the next line appears on 20:21:07 so the crash is during 9 seconds:
[image: Console during crash lines]

Comment: I already looked at the system monitor, i forget to say it i'll add it.
When the freeze happens the CPU is at 30% and disks are not at 100% when ii download but when I copy anything they are at 100% So it's weird, the amount of RAM used changes nothing, and the console writes nothing suspect

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I uploaded a few pictures. This freeze happened when i copied things into an USB key

Comment: OK thank you, you are running pretty loaded :) Menu bar full, Dock full :), and you have a continuous error in the Console from the Telegram Desktop ? There is simple Terminal command to see all processes and the load to the system. Type "Top" and observe what it does under normal conditions, then try the large file copy/paste.

Comment: Could you disable the 2 trouble makers (Telegram Desktop and Fantastical)

Comment: I tested to copy files with telegram opened, it freezed, then I quitted Telegram, Zero freezes, then a just started Telegram (without copying) and i got a freeze, So i think it's Telegram the cause of the problem, but I can't understand why (it's very weird because Telegram is a simple messaging app) so but I have uninstalled Telegram, i'l report if I get another freeze during the next days, If i don't get one i solve this topic with answer that the unofficial Telegram app makes freeze the mac. Thank you for your help !! You was very helpfull.

Comment: I tested also with the top command but nothing changes during a freeze or before, (i checked the telegram line) but the DesktopService uses a litle more ressources but only a little i don't think it has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I installed OS X EL Capitan, (10.11) and i started to transfer a 9Gigs app (xCode) to install it, and I had NO freeze, so it is Yosemite, and fixed in OS X El Capitan :)  It was only a quick test but On Yosemite doing this froze the system every minute. 
If I get one freeze during the next days I'l Edit this post. If not I resolve it.

Anyway, thank you for your help :)

**Okay it wasn't OS X but Hardware, The second SSD was installed in the Optical Super Drive bay, and on Late 2011 Mac Book Pro there is an issue on the controller so I installed OS X on the Hard Drive without using the SSD, NO freeze, so I decided to swap SSD and Hard Drive but I don't have the right Screwdriver**

---

Answer (score 0):

I do not why, but the Telegram App could be the cause since it is flooding your Console log with problems.

The second one is the Fantastical app.

I recommend you either fix those apps or disable them.

**U P D A T E**

Thank your for the logs. As said you have many 3d party apps that are not behaving and creating a lost of errors. For example the Fantastical is still running and making problems. The "MiniPlayer" is making problems. The "dayone" app is making problems.

Hold alt+cmd+esc that will bring up new window showing running applications. Stop all applications that you do not immediately need.

- You also have Flashback Trojan (virus). That can happen without your knowledge, you ran across a site which installed the Flashback Trojan. It is now residing in the

> Agents de lancement pour l’utilisateur : ??

```
[engagé]    com.valvesoftware.steamclean.plist
```

Remove it using [instructions from Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1517?locale=en_US).

Here is the list of some Applications that need fixing (or removal)

- > MiniPlayer

  is a iTunes product. So normally it should work but not on your system. Try to disable (switch it off) in the iTunes with keyboard shortcut "alt+cmd+m". If it is not working you would need a iTunes update.
- Fantastical 2.app

check this out http://flexibits.com/fantastical/help/widgets-and-extensions

- Clear Day.app
- Opera Helper
- dayoneapp.dayone-agent

Comment: I've got another two freezes today, without Telegram App installed and without copying data,  when i written these lines a third crash is occured... i also killed FantastiCal app and it still froze.. I don't have any idea anymore but it froze more with Telegram open and installed so it can be the many errors in the console ? but I don't know where they come from...

Comment: these are the last line and the first line before and after the freeze in the console

03/06/2015 18:56:50,837 iTunes[445]: ### PlayQueue::StartPlayingNextInternal: played off the end of the queue

03/06/2015 18:59:19,535 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ReportCrash[900]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash

Comment: Difficult to say, since you have so many 3d party apps that can do that. Copy a long Console report (not screen shot) and post it in a place with link to it. Also I would suggest to profile your system using the EtreCheck http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck

Comment: There is the last full log of my console: https://paste.ee/r/kxZgs
there is the EtreCheck: https://paste.ee/r/UvuNe
Your command line outputs nothing..

Comment: I read some things about this FlashBack virus, it must be installed by a plugin, but i don't have installed Flash exactly for this reason because Flash is full of malwares. I only installed java from the official Java site for playing minecraft and don't enabled it on by browsers.. It can be the not bought softwares...

Comment: I think it is bit more complicated. If you have Java enabled in browsing you could have gotten it without your knowledge. Anyway, your system shows you have it, so get rid of it. Some website need Java enabled, some not. You might have got that virus before Java made a update to prevent it. It is in your automatic start up, so that alone is  problem.

Comment: It's very strange because, I said it in my original post I reinstalled completly OSX it is 2 weeks ago so very weird..  I must install one app after the other and look when it shows me this Steam thing (I thinked it's normal process i have steam installed)
It can be a game, the creator of this virus must logic to insert his virus into a cracked game installer where is on steam

Comment: And i used the Apple Remove tool, rebooted and it's still appears in EtreCheck :(

Comment: Well, you have computer freezes. You also have extremely high number of problems in the Console, of different kind. I am surprised your computer works at all. We can try to resolve all those problem to stop the freezes one by one. Reinstalling the OS X will not help here, since you are still using a lot of 3d party apps that crate the problems and those have nothing to do with the OS X it self.

Comment: Why can I not use 3rd party applications.. it's a computer if I can't use 3party apps I don't know why, I don't understand ^^

I have many apps in the dock but I don't use them all the times only when I need them so don't know :(  I check the console and delete the error making apps

Comment: Yes, you can use any 3d party app that does not creates problems. Why would you need autostart for all those apps ? look in Agents de lancement, Daemons de lancements, Agents de lancement pour l’utilisateur ? they just consume computer power. Lets say you want Skype and TeamViewer to auto Start, but nothing else.

Comment: How do i remove these Agents and daemons ? is there a tool ?
Edit: Found one it's named Lingon: https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/

Comment: Woa i can't look at the weather and I must stop browsing ? It's crazy... I hate chrome firefox lacks functions, Safari freeze every 5 secs.. I have no alternatives... I think I wait 10.11 hoping Apple makes bug fixes..

Comment: You can not keep installing Junk and expect your computer to work. You do not have to remove any of the apps, but you need to find a fix for them, or find another app that does the same without poisoning.

Comment: It's hard to find.... The developers are making crap always new things but never optimizing there code...

Comment: So I deleted all the apps who making problems but it continues to freeze.. More when it overheats or using the disk or VMware for example. It can finally be a hardware issue ... But how to determine what? I started Mac OS from external hard drive over USB and there where no freeze. I don't tested it with high usage so don't know finally I think I test it again if it works without freeze Il say it's the SSDs fault or the Sata cable/controller ? I can also test to install osx of the second hard drive but it's very slow OS X of a hard drive